# How to hide whole row if some cells are empty in php and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-table, hide

I want to hide an entire row if some of the cells are null. I have tried various method using CSS and JS but none of it is working.

The first column is filled but the other two columns in a row are blank or data will be fetched from mySQL if user inputs the data.

Even if first column is filled entire row should hide if no data is there in other cells in a row.

```html
<div class="container-sm border mb-4">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h3 class="mt-3" style="text-align: center; ">User Complaints</h3>
    </div>
    <table id="table" class="table">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" width="300px"> Complaint Type</th>
          <th scope="col" width="400px"> Username / IP</th>
          <th scope="col"> Remark</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php 
                    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","***","","***");
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comp  ORDER BY complaint_id DESC  Limit 1 ";

                    $result = $con -> query($sql); 

                    if($result-> num_rows > 0 ){
                        while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
                ?>
        <tr>
          <th><label for="">SNMP Settings</label></th>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row['snmpip']; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row['snmpremark']; ?>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th><label for="">IP Settings</label></th>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row['ipip']; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row['ipremark']; ?>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th><label for="">Antivirus Settings</label></th>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row['antiip']; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row['antiremark']; ?>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th><label for="">BTS Settings</label></th>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row['btsip']; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row['btsremark']; ?>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th><label for="">BOOST Settings</label></th>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row['boostip']; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row['boostremark']; ?>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <?php } }?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the CSS and JS code you tried so that we can help you debug it. Also note that you have some invalid HTML - you open a `<th>` tag but close a `</td>`

Comment: If you want to do this client side (JS & CSS) after the table has been rendered, then please remove the PHP tag since it's irrelevant where the data originally comes from. If you want to remove it while generating the table using PHP, then please add that code. Since you say that you have tried various methods, you should show it to us and explain what happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very simply with some basic javascript. Find all table-cell elements using `querySelectorAll` - from which you know the parent is the `table-row`. If the `table-cell` is empty ( or other criteria ) manipulate the parent - hide it in this case.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach( td=>{
  let tr=td.parentNode;
  if( td.textContent=='' )tr.style.display='none'
})
```

```html
<table id="mytable" width="500" class="table">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" width="300px"> Complaint Type</th>
      <th scope="col" width="400px"> Username / IP</th>
      <th scope="col"> Remark</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th><label for="">SNMP Settings</label></th>
      <td name="tdTable">Hello </td>
      <td name="tdTable"> World</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><label for="">IP Settings</label></th>
      <td name="tdTable"></td>
      <td name="tdTable"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th><label for="">Antivirus Settings</label></th>
      <td> </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>Trial</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Trail 2</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion

Test if the tr is already hidden and if not, hide it if the cell is empty

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#mytable tbody tr td").forEach(td => {
  const tr = td.closest("tr")
  tr.hidden = tr.hidden || td.textContent.trim() ===  "";
})
```

```html
<table id="mytable" width="500" class="table">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" width="300px"> Complaint Type</th>
      <th scope="col" width="400px"> Username / IP</th>
      <th scope="col"> Remark</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th><label for="">SNMP Settings</label></th>
      <td name="tdTable">Hello </td>
      <td name="tdTable"> World</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><label for="">IP Settings</label></th>
      <td name="tdTable"></td>
      <td name="tdTable"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><label for="">Antivirus Settings</label></th>
      <td> </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Trial</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Trail 2</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Same in jQuery

```js
$("#mytable tbody tr td").each(function() {
  const $tr = $(this).closest("tr")
  const emptyCells = $tr.find("td").filter(function() { return $(this).text().trim() === ""; }).length > 0;
  $tr.toggle(!emptyCells)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable" width="500" class="table">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" width="300px"> Complaint Type</th>
      <th scope="col" width="400px"> Username / IP</th>
      <th scope="col"> Remark</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th><label for="">SNMP Settings</label></th>
      <td name="tdTable">Hello </td>
      <td name="tdTable"> World</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><label for="">IP Settings</label></th>
      <td name="tdTable"></td>
      <td name="tdTable"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><label for="">Antivirus Settings</label></th>
      <td> </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Trial</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Trail 2</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what you are looking for using jQuery:

```js
$('tr').each(function(){
            var _hide = false;
            $(this).find('td').each(function(){
                if($(this).text().trim() == ''){
                    _hide = true;
                }
            });
            if(_hide){
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable" width="500" class="table" >
        <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" width="300px"> Complaint Type</th>
            <th scope="col" width="400px"> Username / IP</th>
            <th scope="col"> Remark</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody >
        <tr>
            <th class="head"><label for="">SNMP Settings</label></th>
            <td name="tdTable">Hello </td>
            <td name="tdTable"> World</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th ><label for="">IP Settings</label></th>
            <td name="tdTable"></td>
            <td name="tdTable"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="">Antivirus Settings</label></th>
            <td> </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Trial</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Trail 2</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```